# calculating percentiles for multiple columns in R

Tags: r

I need to calculate the quantiles at following probability values 0.05,0.25,0.50,0.75,0.90,0.95,0.99,1 for 100 variables excluding time

Data structure is as below

datasetname-df

```
time Var1 var2 var3.....var100

 1    100   230  378......300

 2    200  145  129......240

 3    150  235  200 .... 690
```

I am using the below logic.

```
percentiles <- do.call("rbind",tapply(df[2:100],quantile,probs=c(0,0.05,0.25,0.50,0.75,0.90,0.95,0.99,1),na.rm=TRUE))
```

Since this runs only on vectors, it would be difficult to call all 100 variables.

Comment: I think it is better you read the documentation of `?tapply`.  You may need `lapply` instead of `tapply`

Comment: @akrun - Above code works for a list (with apply function). However, how can we get same result with a dataframe?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Why use tapply? Just using apply seems fine here, e.g.:

```
quants <- c(0,0.05,0.25,0.50,0.75,0.90,0.95,0.99,1)
apply( df[2:100] , 2 , quantile , probs = quants , na.rm = TRUE )
```

Comment: @DavidHeckmann Hey! How can you get a same result but arrange  probabilities on columns. I tried your code and I get the quantities mentioned on rows and variables on columns. I want to get quantiles on columns and variables on rows. Some quick fix in this one-liner code?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you. the current code applies `quantile` to columns. In order to apply it to rows, use apply(df[2:100] , 1 , ...), the second agrument specifies the "direction" of the apply.